# Issues connecting to GAPI through an Appflow built React project

Tags: reactjs, google-api-js-client, ionic-appflow

I've built an app using React js and built that as an ipa file (the target devices are iPads) using Ionic AppFlow. This app utilises a google drive connection to create folders and upload files, which I've tested while running through both `npm start` and `ionic serve` and have been able to verify that the google drive authentication and functionality work as intended when run on Chrome on Windows and Safari on both mac OS and iOS. Post-build, I get an error that reads that me.a.client.drive is undefined, with that error being consistent regardless of if I'm using `import { gapi } from 'gapi-script'` or loading it (through the same npm module) to load gapi as part of the window using the `loadGapiInsideDOM` function. Is there something I'm missing about how to set up a functional google drive client using this setup? Thanks!